# Who "owns" a collection in OpenSea?

Tags: opensea, verification

As of this question writing (Oct 2022), OpenSea on its [website](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/360063519133-What-is-a-verified-account-or-badged-collection-) states : *"Once your account is verified, any collection with at least 75 ETH of volume (or equivalent in SOL) will be eligible to be badged"*. My question is: Per my understanding, a collection may have multiple owners (i.e., unique owners of assets within the collection). So in the stated requirement *"Once your account is verified.."*, which "account" is this requirement referring to? Is this referring to ALL owner account(s) of the collection OR the approved editor(s) of the collection OR something else?  I guess I am confused about what collection "owner" actually means. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

**The direct answer to your question is the account that created the collection, owns it.**

More details for anyone who needs:

Verification and the badge two different things.
Accounts are verified and the collections are badged.

If the **"creator"** account is verified then the requirement is 75 ETH of volume for a collection to be badged.

Account verification rules:

> Before you can apply for account verification, your account must have:
>
> Ownership of a collection with at least 75 ETH of volume sold (or equivalent in >SOL)
>
> - username
> - profile picture
> - verified email address
> - connected Twitter account

Comment: Note: Even if the account has all those requirements for verification, there is no guarantee that your account will be verified. Those requirements are only for applying to be verified.

Comment: Thanks, Yetik. This is a very helpful response. I think this construct should be much better documented on OpenSea docs.  Example: In the OpenSea Collection Model page
("https://docs.opensea.io/reference/collection-model"), there isn't a "Collection creator" field in its schema.  In fact, the description mentions "Collections have one or more owners and are typically associated with important metadata such as creator royalties and descriptions." I found this incredibly confusing.